# What is the difference between json.load() and json.loads() functions

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

In Python, what is the difference between `json.load()` and `json.loads()`?

I guess that the *load()* function must be used with a file object (I need thus to use a context manager) while the *loads()* function take the path to the file as a string. It is a bit confusing.

Does the letter "**s**" in `json.loads()` stand for **string**?

Comment: *`json.loads(s, *)` - Deserialize `s` (a `str`, `bytes` or `bytearray` instance containing a JSON document)* - https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html

Answer (score 285, accepted):

Yes, `s` stands for string. The `json.loads` function does not take the file path, but the file contents as a string. Look at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads).

Simple example:

```py
with open("file.json") as f:
  data = json.load(f)  # ok

  data = json.loads(f)  # not ok, f is not a string but a file
```

```py
text = '{"a": 1, "b": 2}'  # a string with json encoded data
data = json.loads(text)
```

Comment: Linked article points to the wrong python version. Question is tagged as 2.7.

Comment: The mentioned documentation for Python 3: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load

Answer (score 136):

Just going to add a simple example to what everyone has explained,

**json.load()**

`json.load` can deserialize a file itself i.e. it accepts a `file` object, for example,

```
# open a json file for reading and print content using json.load
with open("/xyz/json_data.json", "r") as content:
  print(json.load(content))
```

will output,

```
{u'event': {u'id': u'5206c7e2-da67-42da-9341-6ea403c632c7', u'name': u'Sufiyan Ghori'}}
```

If I use `json.loads` to open a file instead,

```
# you cannot use json.loads on file object
with open("json_data.json", "r") as content:
  print(json.loads(content))
```

I would get this error:

> TypeError: expected string or buffer

**json.loads()**

`json.loads()` deserialize string.

So in order to use `json.loads` I will have to pass the content of the file using `read()` function, for example,

using `content.read()` with `json.loads()` return content of the file,

```
with open("json_data.json", "r") as content:
  print(json.loads(content.read()))
```

**Output,**

```
{u'event': {u'id': u'5206c7e2-da67-42da-9341-6ea403c632c7', u'name': u'Sufiyan Ghori'}}
```

That's because type of `content.read()` is string, i.e. `<type 'str'>`

If I use `json.load()` with `content.read()`, I will get error,

```
with open("json_data.json", "r") as content:
  print(json.load(content.read()))
```

Gives,

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

So, now you know `json.load` deserialze file and `json.loads` deserialize a string.

**Another example,**

`sys.stdin` return `file` object, so if i do `print(json.load(sys.stdin))`, I will get actual json data,

```
cat json_data.json | ./test.py

{u'event': {u'id': u'5206c7e2-da67-42da-9341-6ea403c632c7', u'name': u'Sufiyan Ghori'}}
```

If I want to use `json.loads()`, I would do `print(json.loads(sys.stdin.read()))` instead.

Comment: Just FYI, with Python 3.6.5  the `with open()` and `json.loads()` returns an exception: `TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'TextIOWrapper'`

Answer (score 35):

Documentation is quite clear: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

```
json.load(fp[, encoding[, cls[, object_hook[, parse_float[, parse_int[, parse_constant[, object_pairs_hook[, **kw]]]]]]]])
```

> Deserialize fp (a .read()-supporting file-like object containing a
>   JSON document) to a Python object using this conversion table.

```
json.loads(s[, encoding[, cls[, object_hook[, parse_float[, parse_int[, parse_constant[, object_pairs_hook[, **kw]]]]]]]])
```

> Deserialize s (a str or unicode instance containing a JSON document)
>   to a Python object using this conversion table.

So `load` is for a file, `loads` for a `string`

Comment: "File like object" vs "a str/unicode instance". I don't understand what's not clear?

Answer (score 30):

### QUICK ANSWER (very simplified!)

> ### json.load() takes a **FILE**
>
> json.load() expects a file (file object) - e.g. a file you opened before given by filepath like `'files/example.json'`.

---

> ### json.loads() takes a STRING
>
> json.loads() expects a (valid) JSON string - i.e. `{"foo": "bar"}`

---

### EXAMPLES

> Assuming you have a file **example.json** with this content: { "key_1": 1, "key_2": "foo", "Key_3": null }

```sh
>>> import json
>>> file = open("example.json")

>>> type(file)
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>

>>> file
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='example.json' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>

>>> json.load(file)
{'key_1': 1, 'key_2': 'foo', 'Key_3': None}

>>> json.loads(file)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/python/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 341, in loads
TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper


>>> string = '{"foo": "bar"}'

>>> type(string)
<class 'str'>

>>> string
'{"foo": "bar"}'

>>> json.loads(string)
{'foo': 'bar'}

>>> json.load(string)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/python/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Comment: Tutorial about  `json.dump`/`dumps` & `json.load`/`loads` https://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python-json-dumps-loads-file-read-write.php

Answer (score 0):

In python3.7.7, the definition of json.load is as below according to [cpython source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.7/Lib/json/__init__.py):

```
def load(fp, *, cls=None, object_hook=None, parse_float=None,
        parse_int=None, parse_constant=None, object_pairs_hook=None, **kw):

    return loads(fp.read(),
        cls=cls, object_hook=object_hook,
        parse_float=parse_float, parse_int=parse_int,
        parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
```

json.load actually calls json.loads and use `fp.read()` as the first argument.

So if your code is:

```
with open (file) as fp:
    s = fp.read()
    json.loads(s)
```

It's the same to do this:

```
with open (file) as fp:
    json.load(fp)
```

But if you need to specify the bytes reading from the file as like `fp.read(10)` or the string/bytes you want to deserialize is not from file, you should use json.loads()

As for json.loads(), it not only deserialize string but also bytes. If `s` is bytes or bytearray, it will be decoded to string first. You can also find it in the source code.

```
def loads(s, *, encoding=None, cls=None, object_hook=None, parse_float=None,
        parse_int=None, parse_constant=None, object_pairs_hook=None, **kw):
    """Deserialize ``s`` (a ``str``, ``bytes`` or ``bytearray`` instance
    containing a JSON document) to a Python object.

    ...

    """
    if isinstance(s, str):
        if s.startswith('\ufeff'):
            raise JSONDecodeError("Unexpected UTF-8 BOM (decode using utf-8-sig)",
                                  s, 0)
    else:
        if not isinstance(s, (bytes, bytearray)):
            raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
                            f'not {s.__class__.__name__}')
        s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in the source of the JSON text

json.load() expects to get the text from a file-like object
json.loads() expects to get its text from a string object

Assume you have a file (json.txt) with the following contents

```
[ {"name": "Fred", "age": 32}, {"name": "Bob", "age": 21 } ]
```

Now study the following:

```
>>> import json 
>>> with open("json.txt") as f:
      j1 = json.load(f) 
>>> j1 
[{u'age': 32, u'name': u'Fred'}, {u'age': 21, u'name': u'Bob'}]
```

## Now using strings

```
>>> with open("json.txt") as f: 
  txt = f.read()  
>>> txt 
'[ { "name": "Fred", "age": 32}, {"name": "Bob", "age": 21 } ]\n\n' 
>>> json.loads(txt) 
[{u'age': 32, u'name': u'Fred'}, {u'age': 21, u'name': u'Bob'}]
```

In the first part, we read the file directly using json.load(). In the section part, we first read the file’s contents into a string variable, then pass that variable to json.loads()

The same relationship holds for json.dump() and json.dumps()