# AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'load'

Tags: python, json, data-analysis

I have json package in my system and have also kept json.py package in same directory where json file is kept. Still I am gitting this error- AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'load'.

code-

```
import json

# Load JSON: json_data
with open("D:\\python\\Datacamp\\world_bank.json") as json_file:
    json_data = json.loads(json_file)

# Print each key-value pair in json_data
for k in json_data.keys():
    print(k + ': ', [k])
```

Comment: Rename your script from `json.py` to something else that is not a built-in or another third party module name

Comment: I have renamed it as rohanpy and tred, still same problem

Comment: Also delete json.pyc as explained in the duplicate.

Comment: can you please share the link of duplicate once.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you should use json.load instead of json.loads. The former is used for loading files, the latter for json strings.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58577952/1067293