# Parsing JSON list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, parsing

I'm trying to retrieve the area value and the first pair of coordinates value for every area from a JSON list of dictionaries after an API call

```
[{'area': 'abcd', 'geojson': '{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[103.8593,1.43905,...[103.6391,1.3527]]]]}'},
 {'area': 'efgh', 'geojson': '{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[100.000,1.4000,...[103.6391,1.3527]]]]}'}
.
.
```

This is my code

```
# calling the API 
results = requests.get(url).json()

area= []
coordinates = []

for i in results:
    a = i['pln_area_n'] 
    area.append(a)

for x in results:
    c = x['geojson']['coordinates'][0]
    coordinates.append(c)
```

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

My code is definitely wrong, how do I access the first pair of coordinates value of the geojson key for every area?

Comment: `x['geojson']` is a **string**, you need to `json.load` it into a dictionary to be able to access the `'coordinates'`. The format of the API you're hitting seems a bit weird, I might be inclined to look at fixing this upstream.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You should post an answer showing how to deal with it. It seems like it's intentional, they did call that property `geojson`, indicating that it contains JSON, not an object.

Comment: @jonrsharpe it is weird, am looking into the api call. json.load and .json() works the same too as discussed in this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39719689/what-is-the-difference-between-json-load-and-json-loads-functions

Comment: What do you mean *"works the same too"*? The point is that you need to parse parts of it *twice*; once to get what you show in your question, then again for the content of the `geojson` values. As @Barmar has pointed out, the name suggests that a JSON string is expected for that value.

Answer (score -1):

I'd guess your response is something like:

```json
[{"area": "abcd", "geojson": "{\"type\": \"MultiPolygon\", ...}"}]
```

The values of the `geojson` property in the JSON *are themselves JSON strings*, and `requests` will only parse the first "level" of this. Hence you end up with the Python list:

```py
[{'area': "abcd', 'geojson': '{"type": "MultiPolygon", ...}'}]
```

where the `results[0]['geojson']` value is still a JSON object string, **not** parsed to a dictionary. This explains the error; `'{"type": "MultiPolygon", ...}'['coordinates']` is trying to index into a *string* using another string, not accessing a dictionary's value by key:

```
>>> '{"type": "MultiPolygon", ...}'['coordinates']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

You therefore need to `import json` and parse the JSON string values again, e.g. using a list comprehension:

```py
coordinates = [
    json.loads(result['geojson'])['coordinates'][0]
    for result in results
]
```

Comment: `json.load` should be `json.loads`