# Reading json file in python

Tags: python, json, jupyter-notebook

I have twitter datasets `test_data` which records more than two records. So, I reformat my `json` to contain an array and then after trying to read the datasets. So far, I have written the following codes:

```py
import json

json_filename = 'test_data.json'
    
with open(json_filename, encoding="utf8") as file:
    array = {'foo': []}
    foo_list = array['foo']
    for line in file:
        obj = json.loads(line)
        foo_list.append(obj)
    
print(json.dumps(array, indent=4))
```

This gives me the following warning

> 'IOPub data rate exceeded. The notebook server will temporarily stop sending output to the client in order to avoid crashing it. To change this limit, set the config variable `--NotebookApp.iopub_data_rate_limit`.'

Any idea how to get data in Jupyter if I have such huge datasets and how to show those datasets in jupyter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't read your file line by line, since in JSON objects are defined on several lines most of the time. Json.load can read from files directly

Comment: actually, `json.loads` can only read from a string, but `json.load` can take input from a file. [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39719689/what-is-the-difference-between-json-load-and-json-loads-functions)