# How to use json.load on a variable instead of a file?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

usually what we do is,

```
var1 = open('data.json')

var2 = json.load(var1)
```

But in my case, I have JSON format data inside a variable called var_json. How to use json.load on this?

Comment: If `var2` contains a JSON-formatted string, `json.loads(var2)` will parse it into a Python dictionary/array.

Comment: Possible Duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/q/39719689/4985099

Comment: @SkyPlayX Thanks for the reply But json.load maintains that nested structure but json.loads isn't.

Comment: @user17475933 What do you mean by "maintains that nested structure"? Both methods parse JSON to a Python dictionary or array exactly like the JSON string is built.

Comment: @user17475933 - Can you add some data sample for see how failed `json.loads` ?